# jQuery Toggling Button Visibility On Click

Tags: jquery, visibility

I'm looking to 'cycle' between two buttons on a click event.  It's trivial to do but I wonder if there is a more concise way to achieve it than what I have below.

```
$('button#start').click( function() {

    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $('button#stop').removeClass('hide');

});

$('button#stop').click( function() {

    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $('button#start').removeClass('hide');

});
```

Comment: With `$('button#stop')`, you don't need the `button`. So, `$('#stop')`. jQuery and Javascript are both performance tuned to quickly find `id` selected elements, and although I think jQuery will optimize your query (eg, remove `button` from the selectors), I consider it a bad habit and certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Another simple demo** http://jsfiddle.net/S4d6j/

Good read: visible selector: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

You can use `.is(":visible")` to check which one is visible and hide the other, and we can chain both buttons.

Hope it helps

**code**

```
$('#start,#stop').click(function() {

    if ((this.value === "start") && $(this).is(":visible")) {        
        $("#stop").show();
    } else if ((this.value === "stop") && $(this).is(":visible")) {
        $("#start").show();
    }

    $(this).hide();

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    $(  
         $(this).addClass('hide').attr('id') == 'start' 
              ? '#stop' 
              : '#start'
    ).removeClass('hide');
});
```

this one will hide the button while it gets the id, it will select the stop id if the current id attribute is start and vice versa.
it uses hide and show but you could substitute in addClass('hide') etc

Comment: Oh lord, don't use a ternary operator like that. Just, no. Reformatting it doesn't *really* help.

Answer (score 1):

It bugs me I'm not caching that `$(this)`, but it's not necessary and won't give any realized performance gains in my opinion. However, I imagine this is about as short as it's going to get:

```
$('#start, #stop').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('button').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/S4d6j/1/

So, it depends on your DOM structure and where the elements are. The alternative could be to just use `this.id` to determine which was clicked and then toggle values accordingly:

```
$('#start, #stop').click(function(){
    var buttons = {start: 'stop', stop: 'start'};

    $(this).hide();
    $('#' + buttons[this.id]).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/S4d6j/3/

EDIT: Made it even more consise with `$(this).hide()`.

No trickiness, Nixonian ternaries, or duplication in the handlers. Just nice and simple.

Comment: Yeah, I outclevered myself there. You gotta get it to get it, got it? Niiice. `:P`